# prevent nut from constantly typing on command line (Debian)

Tags: debian, terminal, ups

I have been using Debian for a short time and when I login with my poor **ssh** user, there is a process that constantly writes to the console and makes me nervous. I get this warning message from nut:

```
Broadcast message from nut@NAS (somewhere) (Sat Apr 16 06:31:25 2022):

UPS salicru@127.0.0.1:3493 is unavailable
```

The thing is my **UPS** is working fine and I have no idea why the warning is coming from. I want it to not appear in the terminal anymore. It is very inconvenient to use the terminal and that message appears every few minutes. Can you tell me how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mesg n` to disallow all messages from other users, including nut.

This will not prevent `nut@NAS` from sending the message, but it will block this particular terminal from receiving them.

However, it's more concerning what is sending this message, but to find out, you need to look at your system... start with `ps axu`, look at `dmesg`, look at syslog, look at the list of users, look at the home directories.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to Linux and everything seems like a mountain to me. If I wanted to revert mesg n how could I turn it back on?

I will investigate on all the commands that you have told me to locate the problem.

Comment: dirkt, it seems that the solution does not work for me, I keep getting the message. Is it possible that the message is coming from the root user and for that reason I can't ignore it?

Comment: You can turn it on again with `mesg y`. Yes, it's possible that it's coming from something with root permissions, and in that case you cannot block it, so then you have to start hunting it down. If you want to experiment with how those messages are sent, the commands are `wall` and `write`. Read `man wall`, `man write`, `man mesg` for details.